# Add existing SSH key to new Mac

Tags: ssh

I'm a bit new to SSH and it's technique, but used it to connect to websites on my old MacBook. 
Since I now have a new one, I want to use the same key if thats possible.
I saved the (ssh-rsa) key in 1Password.
Now I want to overwrite the default "id_rsa" file if that's possible, so my connection is working again. Is this possible and how can I encrypt this key and replace the current key in the id_rsa file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just replace the file?

Comment: I wish, but unfortunately my old one isn't working anymore..

Comment: How is your ssh key stored in 1Password? Is it a file there, a blob of text in a note field, etc?

Comment: Basically you can copy your old id_rsa/id_rsa.pub files from your old Mac. If you have lost either of them, create a new pair and copy the pub key to the sites you want to log in to.

Comment: @negacao The key is stored like: ssh-rsa - Code - Macbook name. I can still add it to several systems, but just don't know how to add it to my own Mac..

Comment: That is your public key, not your private key. The private one should start with a line `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`. You will need the private key to authenticate to those remote systems. There is a good explanation of public vs private keys here: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication

Comment: If you are using 1password 8 then you can store your ssh keys in it https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/ . Thus use 1password on both machines. But note the encrypted data wioll be stored on 1passwords servers which should be secure enough but I can image cases where that external storage would not be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just copy your old key (typically `id_rsa` (private key) and `id_rsa.pub` (public key)) to your new computer to `~/.ssh/`
2. make sure to have the right permissions with `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. then add the key using `ssh-add`
   for example

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`